# How to write this summation in R?

Tags: r

How to write this summation as follows in R?

Here X is a matrix and I want to get this summation with each row of z, like z_1^{(1)}, z_2^{(1)}, ..., z_10^{(1)} for the first summation, and z_1^{(2)}, z_2^{(2)}, ..., z_10^{(2)} for the second summation...

Comment: It would help if you (a) provided some small sample data, (b) show desired output for the sample input, and (c) explained your code attempt. What is the meaning of `l`, `j`, `i`, and `k`. I assume one is the rows, another is the columns (which?) not sure about the other two... I'm also confused by the `setdiff()`... nothing in your text mentions anything that would imply `setdiff` to me. And are you using `z` and `X` interchangeably?

Comment: @GregorThomas Hi, I added the formula for this summation.

Comment: Great. Could you also define all the terms? I see `x`, `y`, and `z` now. What is `n` - the number of rows of `x`? What is `m`? Are `l` and `j` column indices of `x` and `z`?

Comment: @York if my answer is not correct, please tell me why so I can correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given X:

```
x <- matrix(rep(1:10, 10), 10, byrow = TRUE)
x
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
#>  [2,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
#>  [3,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
#>  [4,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
#>  [5,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
#>  [6,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
#>  [7,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
#>  [8,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
#>  [9,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
#> [10,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
```

Power each row by respectively 1, 2, 3, etc..

```
x ^ (1:10)
#>       [,1] [,2]  [,3]    [,4]    [,5]     [,6]      [,7]       [,8]       [,9]
#>  [1,]    1    2     3       4       5        6         7          8          9
#>  [2,]    1    4     9      16      25       36        49         64         81
#>  [3,]    1    8    27      64     125      216       343        512        729
#>  [4,]    1   16    81     256     625     1296      2401       4096       6561
#>  [5,]    1   32   243    1024    3125     7776     16807      32768      59049
#>  [6,]    1   64   729    4096   15625    46656    117649     262144     531441
#>  [7,]    1  128  2187   16384   78125   279936    823543    2097152    4782969
#>  [8,]    1  256  6561   65536  390625  1679616   5764801   16777216   43046721
#>  [9,]    1  512 19683  262144 1953125 10077696  40353607  134217728  387420489
#> [10,]    1 1024 59049 1048576 9765625 60466176 282475249 1073741824 3486784401
#>       [,10]
#>  [1,] 1e+01
#>  [2,] 1e+02
#>  [3,] 1e+03
#>  [4,] 1e+04
#>  [5,] 1e+05
#>  [6,] 1e+06
#>  [7,] 1e+07
#>  [8,] 1e+08
#>  [9,] 1e+09
#> [10,] 1e+10
```

Sum each row.

```
rowSums(x ^ (1:10))
#>  [1]          55         385        3025       25333      220825     1978405
#>  [7]    18080425   167731333  1574304985 14914341925
```